# $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}x^4 \arctan(x)$ problems! (easy I guess)

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

I'm having some trouble calculating this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}x^4 \arctan(x)$$

Because I get: $\infty \times (-\frac\pi2) = ?$

Now, I've learned you can't just treat infinity like a number, it's more like an idea or a concept, so you are not supposed to "multiply" $\infty$ with $-\frac\pi2$ and get $-\infty$.

But the answer to this is $-\infty$, so how do I show that in a valid manner?

Comment: You should try proving for yourself that if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n = b\neq 0$ that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n = \infty$ and/or the related result for limits of functions rather than sequences.  Once you've proven this, you are then effectively allowed to do exactly that and "multiply infinity" just as you hoped you could.  (*Remember to be careful in the case that the limit of the one goes to infinity while the limit of the other goes to zero, that would be an indeterminate form and requires more careful analysis*)

Comment: @JMoravitz That is only true for $b > 0$.

Comment: Fair enough, $\text{sgn}(b)\cdot \infty$ then.  The point remains that it is an accessible early exercise for the beginning student.

Answer (score -1):

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}x^4\arctan(x)=-\infty$$

because
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^4=+\infty$$
and

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\arctan(x)=\frac{-\pi}{2}<0$$

Comment: The OP is asking for justification for why $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)g(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x) \cdot \lim\limits_{x\to c} g(x)$ is valid and why assuming one of those limits resulted in infinity (*and the other did not result in zero*) the resulting multiplication that follows would also be valid

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok, thanks but it is impossible for me to delete from mobile.